# Como podría repetir un stored procedure varias veces?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Quisiera que mi procedimiento almacenado se repitiera hasta que que el contador llegue a 0 pero no funciona. Alguna sugerencia pues no me ejecuta el SP las veces que debería hacerlo. Esta la asigne a un Job que se ejecute a las 13:00

```
Declare @contador as int

Set @contador=(SELECT COUNT(T0.U_GeneraPDF) FROM OINV T0 WHERE T0.U_GeneraPDF='SI')

While(@contador<=0)
Begin
    exec CorreoFacturacion 
    End
End
```

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitarías ejecutar un SP múltiples veces sin parámetros? Algo está mal ahí aparte de no disminuir el valor del contador.

Comment: Por la respuesta eliminada del autor entiendo que se trataría de un error tipográfico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CorreoFacturacion
AS 
BEGIN

    SELECT 'ENTRO EN PROCEDURE';
END
GO
```

Tiene dos problemas el código. La variable @contador nunca se decrementa. Y El while está mal. Debería de ser cuando @contador es mayor que 0 o mayor o igual y no menor o igual.

```
Declare @contador as int

Set @contador=(10); -- Le pongo un número directamente.

While(@contador>=0) -- Mientras contador sea mayor o igual que 0
Begin
    exec CorreoFacturacion;
    set @contador -=1; --decremento de la variable.
    
End;
```

En función de si quieres que se ejecute 10 u 11 veces, cambiarás el `>=` por solo `>`. O lo que es lo mismo, si se tiene que ejecutar siempre al menos 1 vez.

[image: Resultado]